# How print ruby var inside haml in js area?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I am beginner in rails.

I have view that i try to print inside him  @myvar inside js alert.

```
%script(type="text/javascript")
  alert(@myvar);
```

But nothing happens,
What should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should be using [`:javascript` filter](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#javascript-filter) instead of `%script` definition. In javascript filter you are able to use string interpolation. Try this:

```
:javascript
  alert(#{@myvar});
```

Comment: thanks! Also i have problem with spaces in haml - exist option to disable space haml identation?

Comment: No, that's fundamental feature of haml. Can't be turned off :)